# Query regarding a Numpy exercise in Datacamp

Tags: python, numpy

Just started learning python with Datacamp and I ran into a question on Numpy. When doing [this problem](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/intro-to-python-for-data-science/chapter-4-numpy?ex=16)(it's a standalone question so should be easy to understand without any context), I am confused by the instruction:"You can use a little trick here: use np_positions == 'GK' as an index for np_heights".

Nowhere in the code did it link np_heights and np_positions together, how could this index work? At first I thought I had to concatenate the two vertically but it turns out it's not necessary.

Is it because there are only two Numpy arrays and it just so happened that they have the same number of elements, Python decides to pair them up automatically? What if I have multiple Numpy arrays with the same number of elements and I use that index, will it be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing they have in common is their length. Other than that, they are not linked together. The length comes into play when you use [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

Consider the following array:

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

With boolean values, we can index into this array:

```
arr[[True, False, True]]
Out: array([1, 3])
```

This returned values at positions 0 and 2 (where they have `True` values).

This boolean array may come from anywhere. It may come from the same array with a comparison, or from a different array of the same length.

```
arr1 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'])
```

If I do `arr1 == 'a'` it will do an element-wise comparison and return

```
arr1 == 'a'
Out: array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

I can use this in the same array:

```
arr1[arr1=='a']
Out: 
array(['a', 'a'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Or in a different array:

```
arr2 = np.array([2, 5, 1, 7])

arr2[arr1=='a']
Out: array([2, 1])
```

Note that this is no different than `arr2[[True, False, True, False]]`. So we are not actually using `arr1` here. In your example, `np_positions == 'GK'` will return a boolean array too. Since it will have the same size as the `np_height` array, you will only deal with positions where the boolean array has True values.

Comment: Great explanation. In your last example, if the indexing is changed to arr2[[True, False, False]], what would happen? What about arr2[[True, False, False, True, True, False]]? That link on Boolean indexing seem to only talk about dimensional mismatch.

Comment: If the lengths do not match, it raises a warning `__main__:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 2` and if the boolean array is smaller, it assumes the remaining entries are False; otherwise, it just ignores the rest of the boolean array. It will probably raise an error in the future.